# Twitter style URL Regex Matching

Tags: php, regex, url, preg-replace, preg-match

I'm trying to achieve very lax Regex match for a chat client using PHP.

The chat client must be able to pick up both complete and incomplete URLS.

For example:

`http://www.example.com`
or `www.example.com` or `example.com`

I have set up a preg_replace that tries to achieve this:

```
$find = array("/([\w]+:\/\/[\w-?&;#~=\.\/\@]+[\w\/])/is","/(^(?!http:\/\/)[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}(\/?\S*)?)/is");
$replace = array( "<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"http://\\1\">\\1</a>","<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"\\1\">\\1</a>");
$output = preg_replace($find, $replace, $input);
```

So, the aim is to 1st find "complete" URLs with the protocol, then try to find "lazy" URLs that do not have the protocol.

Currently it works great for the "complete" URLs, but the "lazy" URLs do not get picked up.

Comment: the second type, beginning with "www" is pretty straightforward, but the third type, is harder without generating false positives. I use the following for the second type: `/\b(www\.[a-zA-Z0-9\/\\\:\?\%\.\&\;=#\-\_\!\+\~\,]*)/i` Without testing, maybe the initial www\. can be removed to give the third type?

Comment: Hey Tamouse, that worked really well. And it doesn't seem to interfere with the other regex. Please answer and I will accept.

Comment: OK.. so it does seem to interfere with the "complete" RegEx finder. Is there a way to stop it from picking up matches that start with `http://`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after hours of toiling with it.. I managed to find a relatively easy way to match both http:// URLs and www. URLs in order to turn them into anchors.

This is the final solution:

```
$output = preg_replace("/\b((http(s)?:\/\/)?(www\.[a-zA-Z0-9\/\\\:\?\%\.\&\;=#\-\_\!\+\~\,]*))/is","<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"http$3://$4\">$0</a>",$output);
```

Thanks to tamouse for the regex.

Answer (score 5):

I set up something similar a while ago.  My thinking was ... anything that starts with a protocol identifier or a "www" is a URL, plus anything that matches a domain that ends in a valid TLD (two letters, or a known gTLD) if it's followed by a path.  Domains by themselves are just domains.

```
$gtlds="com|net|org|biz|edu|gov|int|pro|xxx";
$gtlds+="|aero|arpa|asia|coop|museum|name|travel";
#$gtlds+="|xn-[a-z0-9]+";
$a = array(
  '/(f|ht)tps?:\/\/[^ ]+/',
  '/(ftp|www)\.[a-z0-9.-]+(/[^ ]*)/',
  "/([a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]*\.)+([a-z]{2}|$gtlds)\/[^ ]*/"
);
```

Note that I'm an old-school regexp user, so this is ERE, not that fancy PREG stuff all the kids are using these days.

The absurdly long list of gTLDs is from [IANA](http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt).  I've updated it so it's valid as of the time of this answer except for `.XN--*`.  You can include the list of TLDs that start with `.XN--` if you like, either with a pattern or by matching them directly and growing the `$gtlds` variable.  I have never encountered any problems caused by simply ignoring their existence, so that's my strategy.

The above REs worked for my specific use.  I make no claim that they'll work for every case that is not mine.  (For example, they will include trailing quotes, if a domain or URL is quoted.  That was never something I had to deal with, so I didn't deal with it.)

Note that when you're doing your replacement, while you want your generator anchor's HREF attribute to be the URL that you match or generate, you probably want to leave the original text as-is for purposes of layout and display.

And depending how you use these, word boundaries may be helpful ... but you already know how to do those.

Comment: that whitelist of TLDs is about to become very useless, with IANA's recent change in policy and auctioning off new TLDs to the highest bidders.

Comment: Hence my proviso, "***valid as of the time of this answer***".

Comment: great answer, but not really what I'm looking for. Anything using Preg that doesn't require the list of domains?

Comment: Couldn't you put $gtlds into an array, and then `implode()` it?  Would that be less prone to errors?

Comment: Yes, you could.  But why bother?  If you're just making a static array in your code, it's functionally equivalent to a static string.  If you test your code before you deploy it, then a syntax error in your string is just as lightly to be found as a syntax error in your array.  The only advantage to making this anything besides "not a static string" would be if you built a management interface for it to allow the list of gTLDs to be adjusted without having to make source code changes.  Not in scope for my project.  If it is for yours, you do whatever works for you.